# Rails 3 - Syntax error - Accessing member of object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

[image]

My app is something like Kijiji's email reply system.
For each post, user can choose to reply to the post.
I get this error when I submit.

```
Undefined method `contact_email' for nil:NilClass
```

I denoted the line that is causing the error below with **

emailinterests_controller.rb

```
def create
    @emailinterest = Emailinterest.new(params[:emailinterest])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @emailinterest.save
            **Notifier.emailinterest_notification(self, @submission).deliver**
            format.html { redirect_to(@emailinterest, :notice => 'Email was successfully sent!') }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @emailinterest, :status => :created, :location => @emailinterest }
        else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @emailinterest.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

"self" refers to the emailinterest object that's being emailed.
@submission should refer to the current object that emailinterest object is interacting with.

notifier.rb

```
**def emailinterest_notification(emailinterest, submission)**
    @emailinterest = emailinterest
    @submission = submission
        **mail :to => submission.contact_email,**
        :from => emailinterest.sender_email,
        :subject => 'actuirl.com - RE:' + submission.title
end
```

---

## FIX

**C:\Rails\actuirl5\app\controllers\emailinterests_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @emailinterest = Emailinterest.new(params[:emailinterest])
    @submission = Submission.find(params[:submission_id])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @emailinterest.save
            Notifier.emailinterest_notification(@emailinterest, @submission).deliver
            format.html { redirect_to(@emailinterest, :notice => 'Email was successfully sent!') }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @emailinterest, :status => :created, :location => @emailinterest }
        else
            format.html { render :action => "new" }
            format.xml  { render :xml => @emailinterest.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

**C:\Rails\actuirl5\app\views\submissions_form_new_emailinterest.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for(emailinterest) do |f| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag :submission_id, value = @submission.id %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :sender_email %><br />
        <%= f.text_field :sender_email %>
    </div>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :sender_email_content %><br />
        <%= f.text_area :sender_email_content %>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

**C:\Rails\actuirl5\app\views\submissions\show.html.erb**

```
<%= render :partial=>"form_new_emailinterest", :locals=>{:emailinterest=>Emailinterest.new} %>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I didn't see you define @submission at anywhere. so, It is null that is correct error. Check where @submission has been create to solve :-)

Good luck

Comment: How should I define it?

'@submission = Submission.find(params[:id])'

I decided to add that, and got this error.

_Couldn't find Submission without an ID_

Comment: that's right, may be just try @submission = Submission.first for testing first. If it work when mean your params[:id] not supply or can't find that id. you can debug or check from development log.

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you reference to

```
**Notifier.emailinterest_notification(self, @submission).deliver**
```

instead of

```
**Notifier.emailinterest_notification(@emailinterest, @submission).deliver**
```

"self" would be the controller but I think you want the @emailinterest.

Comment: yeah ... and the submission thing, too. :)